# PHP / MySQL use SUM result to join table

Tags: php, mysql

seems like I can´t find the right solution. I have this working query:

```
$stateKdnr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(csv_kd_nr) AS cnt, SUM(csv_betrag) as temphf FROM tempimport WHERE csv_zeilenstatus != 'done' GROUP BY csv_kd_nr, csv_name, csv_ort, csv_vorname");
```

now I want to join another table with the result temphf. Basically where temphf between von_hf AND bis_hf.  I tried different approaches, fe:

```
 $stateKdnr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tempimport.*, COUNT(tempimport.csv_kd_nr) AS cnt, SUM(tempimport.csv_betrag) as temphf, hf.* 
            FROM tempimport INNER JOIN hf ON von_hf > temphf AND bis_hf < temphf
            WHERE tempimport.csv_zeilenstatus != 'done' GROUP BY tempimport.csv_kd_nr, tempimport.csv_name, tempimport.csv_ort, tempimport.csv_vorname");
```

but here I get the error, unknown column temphf, which makes sense b/c it´s no column but a result.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks very much!

Comment: **column_alias** cannot be used in a `WHERE` clause, hence the error ! Because when the  `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Comment: yeah I got that. but how can I resolve this?

Comment: Your first query must become a subquery in the from clause of the 2nd query or you filter on the aggregated values in the having clause. Since we do not know your data, it is a bit difficult to say which of th two is the right approach.